# Populate Listview from List

Tags: android, listview

Im trying to populate a listview from a list, this is the method that create my list:

```
 public List<produto> buscarProdutoPorNome(String nome){  
    List<produto> lista = new ArrayList<produto>();  

    String[] columns = new String[]{  
       "upc", "nome", "descricao", "qtd", "nec"};  
    String[] args = new String[]{nome+"%"};  

    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();  
    Cursor c = db.query("produto", columns,   
       "nome like ?", args, null, null, "nome");  

    c.moveToFirst();  
    while(!c.isAfterLast()){  
      produto p = fillProduto(c);  
      lista.add(p);  
      c.moveToNext();  
    }  
    c.close();  
    db.close();  
    return lista;  
  }
```

Im wanna list, but i dont know how, someone can help me?

```
List<produto>lista = produtosDB.buscarProdutoPorNome("");
```

Comment: Can you try it.. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: Pass your list to the BaseAdapter and populate the listview..

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert the List into an array as:

```
producto[] array = lista.toArray(new producto[lista.size()]);
```

and then populate to the ListView as

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<producto>(this, R.layout.list_item, array));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

// Populate the array list from the database

final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

final ArrayAdapter<String> = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);

list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is the simplest way to do it, but will work for a string list only. To have an adapter with your custom class list you will need to create a custom adapter class and a custom view layout in res/layout. Find more info on custom adapters here:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown